# Select category: Rails 4 many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Sorry for my English

I have a create many to many association between articles and categories

this is my article model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
end
```

this is my category model

```
class category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :articles, through: :categorizations
end
```

in this my categorization model

```
class Categorizations < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    belongs_to :category
end
```

then I have create the categories names in the Seed file

but I try to get the categories in a select but I get this Error

```
undefined method category_id' for <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change `<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, :include_blank =>` true %> to `<%= f.collection_select :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true %>`